# Which preposition would you use when you're talking about bank related matters?

Tags: prepositions

When you're talking bank accounts, which preposition do you use?

> I want to close my account at/with/in XX (bank name).

Which preposition would you use here? I came across sentences with **in** and **with**, but all three seem to convey the same meaning to me. Which would you use?

Comment: i would use "my account at" or "my account with". "my account in" isn't correct

Comment: I would use _with_. "The aristocrat who banks with Coutts..." (WS Gilbert)

Comment: Informally, *when you're [talking bank accounts](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22talking+bank+accounts%22),* you might not use ***any*** preposition at all! (a purist might say that should be *talking **about** bank accounts!* :) Seriously though, all three of your suggested prepositions are at least "acceptable" (***in*** is a bit "marginal" though). Or you could sidestep the issue with an "attributive noun" construction and say you want to *close your **Barclays** account*.

Comment: Note that if you're directly addressing a representative of the organisation that you maintain an account with, you have to say *I'm closing my account **with you***. Since you can't use ***at you*** in that context, it's probably best to just learn that ***with*** always works, so you can pretty much forget about ***at***, which sometimes ***won't*** work at all.

Answer (score 1):

"In" doesn't work at all. "At" and "with" are both viable. You can also rearrange the sentence and use no preposition. If your bank is named ABC, you can say "I want to close my ABC account" and this is what I'd personally say.